# Values are not copied to new Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, selection, copy-paste, advanced-filter

The final code is this

```
Sub Unique_Values_Worksheet_Variables()

'1 Code + Sub splitByChars
    
    Const Chars As Long = 4
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("export")
    Dim dws As Worksheet:
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    sws.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=dws.Range("A:A"), _
        Unique:=True
          
    dws.Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Dim rng As Range:
    Set rng = dws.Range("A1:B1", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    rng.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

Unfortunately this was just focused on one part which has to be copied, the values for these columns were in another column so i try to switch the code

```
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("export")
    Dim dws As Worksheet:
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))

    sws.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=dws.Range("A:A"), _
        Unique:=True
```

to this. I used the macro reader for it.

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Makro
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.ActiveSheet
    Dim dws As Worksheet:
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    sws.Columns("C:C").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
    Columns("D:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("C:J").Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=dws.Range("A1")
   
    
End Sub
```

**what works:**

1. the code recognizes the part with the new worksheet dws.
2. it filters in sws the column C:C, what means
3. it also recognizes sws

**what does not work:**

by copy paste the range no values are hand over.

I have to use the advanced filter on C:C by avoiding duplicates, then i have data which i do not want to handover in column "D:I". The only thing what i want to hand over is column C & J. So i tried it with hiding the columns in between but it does not work.

Has anybody an idea?

i also tried it with `.Delete` what actually would be not that nice.

Is it a problem that i just assigned A1 for pasting it?

```
 Selection.Copy Destination:=dws.Range("A1")
```

Comment: you are using sws.Columns in some lines but then drop the `sws` from subsequent lines. For ease add in a `With sws` code block and use the preceding dot notation to assign the columns to copy from the relevant worksheet. You should also be able to take the selection out and do a straight `.Columns("C:J").Copy Destination:=dws.Range("A1")`

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Columns (Unique)

**About Your Solution**

- Your solution is pretty cool. You probably meant to hide `D:I` though, which is a minor issue.
- After hiding and filtering you might consider unhiding the columns and removing the filter to bring the source worksheet to the initial state.
- I prefer using a worksheet with a name instead of `ActiveSheet`, but it's no big deal if you know what you're doing.
- I don't like the references to the whole columns i.e. letting Excel (VBA) decide which range should be processed.

**About the following**

- I first wrote the second code which is kind of more efficient but comes with the cost of not being able to control the order of the columns (due to `Union`) to be copied, hence the first code is recommended.
- You can easily replace the source worksheet (`Worksheets(sName)`) with `ActiveSheet` if necessary.
- It is assumed that the source data (table (one row of headers)) starts in cell `A1`. Otherwise, you may need to create the source range reference in a different way.
- Adjust (play with) the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyColumnsUnique()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sUniqueColumn As String = "C"
    Const sCopyColumnsList As String = "C,J" ' exact order of the columns
    ' Destination (new worksheet)
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sCopyColumns() As String: sCopyColumns = Split(sCopyColumnsList, ",")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = wb.Worksheets _
        .Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Range(dFirst)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Columns(sUniqueColumn).AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, , , True
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 0 To UBound(sCopyColumns)
            .Columns(sCopyColumns(n)).Copy dCell
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(, 1)
        Next n
        .Parent.ShowAllData
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Sub copyColumnsUniqueAsc()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sUniqueColumn As String = "C"
    Const sCopyColumnsList As String = "C,J" ' forced ascending order of columns
    ' Destination (new worksheet)
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sCopyColumns() As String: sCopyColumns = Split(sCopyColumnsList, ",")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Columns(sUniqueColumn).AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, , , True
        ' Using 'Union' will force the resulting columns be in ascending order.
        ' If 'sCopyColumnsList' is "C,J,D", the order will be "C,D,J".
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 0 To UBound(sCopyColumns)
            If srg Is Nothing Then
                Set srg = .Columns(sCopyColumns(n))
            Else
                Set srg = Union(srg, .Columns(sCopyColumns(n)))
            End If
        Next n
    End With
    
    srg.Copy wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Range(dFirst)
    srg.Parent.ShowAllData
      
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: ..your first procedure which i use, where do you exactly determine that just unique values shall be filtered? I looked for something like  Unique:=True but its not part of the code. Then i changed True to False in ".Columns(sUniqueColumn).AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, , , True" and it worked but just if i change it afterwards again to True because if i dont do that i can not work on the sheets anymore(Error 1004). So is there any adaption possibility that i exclude empty cells in C and remove the setting Unique? Thank you :) PS values in C can have different values in J, which i cant excl.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tragmor

for everyone who has same kind of problems, this could solve it

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Makro
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.ActiveSheet
    Dim dws As Worksheet:
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With sws

    .Columns("C:C").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
    .Columns("D:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    .Columns("C:J").Copy Destination:=dws.Range("A1")
    
    End With
   
    
End Sub
```